# Need example code for PayPal NVP api request code for parallel payment

Tags: api, paypal, parallel-processing, payment, nvp

I can use successfully  the PayPal NVP api for SetExpressCheckout. But the problem with this is, I can't pay two merchant on a single payment. So, going through PayPal, I found that I can use the parallel payment. I need to know how can I use the parallel payment. I have request code for the SetExpressCheckout like following, 
`<form method=post action=https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp>
<input type=hidden name=USER value="xxxxxxxxxxxxx@xxxxx.com">
<input type=hidden name=PWD value="xxxxxxxxx">
<input type=hidden name=SIGNATURE value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
<input type=hidden name=VERSION value=2.3>
<input type=hidden name=PAYMENTACTION value=Order>
<input name=AMT value=10.0>
<input type=hidden name=RETURNURL value=xxxxxx>
<input type=hidden name=CANCELURL value=xxxxxx>
<input type=submit name=METHOD value=SetExpressCheckout>
</form>` 
I need something like the above where I can request for parallel payment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I got the sample codes for parallel payment implementation [PapPal SDK link](https://www.x.com/community/ppx/sdks#NVP).